# Can we call a function within a function call after defining it

Tags: java

hi this may be a stupid question but i still got a doubt . can we call a function call with in a function call

```
public void method1(String s) {
}

public string method2 {
    return some_string;
}

String x; 
method1(x = method2());
```

Comment: Yes., since `x = method2()` is an expression you can use that as an argument.

Comment: Yes. What happened when you tried it?

Comment: What does this have to do with scala?

Comment: YES you can. But wow you will make a great java programmer one day, trust me... I am on SO, so i must be saying the truth... just test simple ideas first before asking the internet...

Comment: ya i have tested it but it shows an error error: type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: String
       info.infos(xyz=obj.method());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said: Yes

As konzo said, for something this simple, why not just try it to see if it works? However, your sample code has some errors. Here's a test:

```
public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      Test test = new Test();
      test.runTest();
  }

  public void method1(String s) {
      System.out.println("in method1 with \"" + s + "\"");
  }

  public String method2() {
      return "method2";
  }

  public void runTest() {
      String x; 
      method1(x = method2());
      System.out.println("x=\"" + x + "\"");
  }
}
```